How do I have full menu pop up on responsive burger hit and not have to hir second link
I have this UL LI dropdwon menu code.  When mobile view the responsive shows the burger?  But when users hits the burger, then the menu link appears only, and the user then has to hit that link to get the menu to dropdown.  When on desktop the MENU link is there so one hit brings down the dropdwon.
Secondly, I would like to always just have the burger on desktop also, I assume that is in the CSS responsive styling.  Havent looked yet as I still ahve the first issue.


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><br />
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color: white" href="#">MENU<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">TITLE 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">TITLE 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu B</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">TITLE 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu D</a></li>
            </br>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



I have tried doing to data-toggles of "collapse" and "dropdown" but that doesnt work.
Please help.
Ron R
